# Distance between center of side of regular polygon inscribed in a circle, and the perimeter of that circle?

Tags: circles

**Point A** : The center of a side of a polygon inscribed in a circle

**Point B** : The point on the perimeter of that circle that is opposite **Point A**

I want to calculate the distance between Point A & Point B

I know the number of sides the polygon has and the radius of the circle it's inscribed in.

I believe this is the way to calculate the length of the side of a regular polygon with n sides (Please correct me if I'm wrong as I am not a mathematician and found this online) :

```
x = nrsin(π/n)
```

Now is the distance I'm looking for : `distance = 2r - x` ?

I'm trying to figure out a formula that I could use in a bit of code I'm writing

Comment: Do you mean an inscribed polygon? So that the vertices are on the circle itself? In that case the distance is 0 because the side is touching the circle. If you want to calculate the distance from the center of a side, draw a triangle with vertices at the center of the circle and at the ends of a side and subtract the altitude from the radius.

Comment: Ah yes, sorry for not being clear Matt. I want to calculate the distance between the center of a side of the polygon and the point on the perimeter of the circle right opposite that center. I want to use Math to do that as I will use it a bit of Javascript code I am writing. I will update the OP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The length of a side is $2r sin(\frac{\pi}{n})$ by trigonometry.

The distance is $r(1-cos\frac{\pi}{n})$, which is the difference between the radius and the length of the line from the center of the circle to the center of the side.

Comment: That's perfect! Thanks!